# What are the allowed characters for DSE Graph label names and property keys?

Tags: graph, datastax, graph-databases, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

What are the allowed characters for DSE Graph Vertex/Edge label names and Property Keys?

Titan allowed any value, and we had some of our labels namespaced with `.` characters. Trying to import our data into DSE Graph throws an exception telling us that `.` characters are not supported in label names.

I couldn't find this limitation documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataStax documentation says "[Allowed characters for the name are alphabetical or underscore](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/reference/schema/refProperties.html)"
for vertex and property labels. Indicating dot (.) is not allowed.